# How do I know which file does href directs to?

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a project right now, and it's confusing reading somebody else's code, especially there are lots. So in a template file, code like:

`<li><a href="<?php echo BASE_URL; ?>?cmd=Reports&action=NonReceived">Non received</a></li>`

Is there a way to know which **PHP** file this URL is referring to?

Comment: What web server and/or framework are you using? This would be going to the base url, which typically points to something like index.php, in this case the url would also include the query parameters `?cmd=Reports&action=NonReceived`

Comment: You should take a look in config file. It should contain all constants for this project. You can find your url over there.

Comment: Look for `define('BASE_URL', ...)` somewhere in the code.

Comment: I'm using Apache Web Server, so the parameters '''?cmd=Reports&action=NonReceived''' should also show up in some other files?

Comment: Open the project in a modern IDE (such as php storm). With any good IDE it should be trivial to find where that constant is defined, For example, in phpstorm, CTRL+clicking on the `BASE_URL` will take you directly to where it is defined where you should be able to see the value.

Comment: Try looking for $_GET['cmd'] to hopefully find where the parameters are used. Other methods of extracting the parameters are available though!